# getResourceId in a custom control returns default value in Eclipse edit mode

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm attempting to get the resource ID of another control in a layout from the constructor of a custom control, using a reference from a custom attribute.

The control works beautifully at runtime, but in the editor it throws the exception shown below.

This code was shamelessly ripped from the SlideDrawer Android source, so I know it must work, and there's something I'm doing wrong.

The constructor of the custom control contains this...

```
mHandleId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Panel_handle, 0);
    if (mHandleId == 0) {
        e = new IllegalArgumentException(a.getPositionDescription() + 
                ": The handle attribute is required and must refer to a valid child.");
    }
```

The layout looks like this

```
<com.xenosoft.hunted.widgets.Panel
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xenosoft.hunted"
    android:id="@+id/message_panel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    app:handle="@+id/message_panel_handle"
    app:content="@+id/message_panel_content"
    app:position="left"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_panel_handle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000">

     </ImageView>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/message_panel_content"
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000">  
      </LinearLayout>

</com.xenosoft.hunted.widgets.Panel>
```

Comment: Don't know if you figured this out, but did you put this code within isInEditMode() by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You have `@+id/message_panel_handle` and  `@+id/message_panel_content` defined twice when the ID can only be defined once. Reference how to position views using RelativeLayout. It should be:

```
<com.xenosoft.hunted.widgets.Panel
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xenosoft.hunted"
    android:id="@+id/message_panel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    app:handle="@+id/message_panel_handle"
    app:content="@+id/message_panel_content"
    app:position="left"
    >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@id/message_panel_handle"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000">

     </ImageView>

     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/message_panel_content"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">  
      </LinearLayout>

</com.xenosoft.hunted.widgets.Panel>
```